# How to prove P / Q or not Q without using any assumption?

Tags: natural-deduction

How to prove ( q or not q), which is tautology when an arbitrary premise is given? (Using natural deduction)

I tried to make steps that finally goes to HS but failed.

Comment: Sorry, it was not to use assumption. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: q is true, therefore q or x is true for any x, especially for x= not q
Case 2: q is false, therefore not q is true, therefore x or not q is true for any x, especially for x=q
Because by law of exclused middle, q has to be false or true, those cases are exhaustive.

Edit:
q or not q= not(not q and not not q)= not (not q and q)= not (False)=True 
using excluded middle in step 2

Comment: That's correct proof, but I don't think that can be expressed in form of natural deduction without using any assumption.

Comment: I changed it not to use any assumptions, except basic logical rules

Answer (score 0):

Not every proof system will be able to prove this without any assumption.  And when you say 'natural deduction' ... that could mean quite a few different proof systems!  Maybe you could let us know what rules of inference you have?